# loop for, and arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, vector

```
VALOR_VETOR = 6
nota1 = []
nota2 = []
nota3 = []
mediaAluno = []
soma1 = 0
soma2 = 0
soma3 = 0
somaMedia = 0
mediaTurma = 0
print("Digite as notas dos alunos\n\n")
for i in range (VALOR_VETOR):
    print(f"Aluno {i}")
    valor = float(input(f"Nota 1: "))
    nota1.append(valor)
    valor = float(input(f"Nota 2: "))
    nota2.append(valor)
    valor = float(input(f"Nota 3: "))
    nota3.append(valor)
    valor = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3)/3
    mediaAluno.append(valor)
    print (f"Nota final = {mediaAluno[i]:.1f}")
for i in range (VALOR_VETOR):
    soma1 = soma1 + nota1
    soma2 = soma2 + nota2
    soma3 = soma3 + nota3
    somaMedia = somaMedia + mediaAluno
mediaProva1 = soma1/VALOR_VETOR
print(f"A media da primeira prova é = {mediaProva1:.1f}")
mediaProva2 = soma2/VALOR_VETOR
print(f"A media da segunda prova é = {mediaProva2:.1f}")
mediaProva3 = soma3/VALOR_VETOR
print(f"A media da primeira prova é = {mediaProva1:.1f}")
mediaTurma = somaMedia/VALOR_VETOR
```

I am a python learner
try, searched, but could not do.
please help me.

line 23, in 
valor = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3)/3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: nota1,... are all lists. If you want to get the value, try nota1[i],... which will give you the ith value

Comment: You don't need loops. Just use `soma1 = sum(nota1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of 500+ /  [so many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unsupported+operand+type%28s%29+for+%2F%3A+%27list%27+and+%27int%27+) ...

Answer (score 1):

- When you use the '+' operator with lists it will return a list with all the 3
  lists concatenated
  for example:

  ```
  l1 = [1,2] 
  l2 = [5,7]
  l  = l1 + l2 #  [1,2,5,4]
  ```

I think you expect to get l =[6,9]

also the operator '/' is not defined for a list

so l/3 will return an error

if you want to to sum individual elements in a list you can use below code
i used for loop for clarity but you can use list comprehension or lambda or ...

```
l =[]
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l.append(l1[i] + l2[i])
""" to make the division we can use the same for loop or make another 
    loop"""

for x in range(len(l)):
    l[x] = l[x]/3
```

Comment: Using enumerate is "cleaner" .... `for x in range(len(l)):` ==> `for idx,value in enumerate(l): l[idx] /= 3`

Comment: The ideal would be the mediaAluno variable with the sums and division by 3 of the variable nota1, nota2 and nota3 in the first for loop, to achieve this result:

Aluno 0: 
Nota 1 = 5
Nota 2 = 7
Nota 3 = 9

Nota final = 7.00

Aluno 1:
Nota 1 = 8
Nota 2 = 3
Nota 3 = 5
Nota final = 5.33

Aluno 2:         
Nota 1 = 7       
Nota 2 = 5
Nota 3 = 3
Nota final = 5.00

A media da primeira prova e: 6.67
A media da segunda prova e: 5.00
A media da terceira prova e: 5.67
A media da nota final e: 5.78

Answer (score 0):

```
 valor = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3)/3  //error

try this line of code as:
valor=(sum(nota1)+sum(nota2)+sum(nota3))/3   //it should work
```

Comment: valor = sum(sum(nota1)+sum(nota2)+sum(nota3))/3 
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: valor = (nota1 + nota2 + nota3)/3  //error

try this line of code as:
valor=(sum(nota1)+sum(nota2)+sum(nota3))/3   //it should work